# ReactJS - I am getting the error"r Invariant failed - not use <Link> outside a <Router>" - this happens in one page but not other pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In one of my modules I use this code without any issue:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

         <Link to="/HowItWorks">
             Continue
         </Link>
```

But in another module I use similar code but get the invarient failed message

```
         import { Link } from "react-router-dom";         
         <Link to="/TheBook">Continue</Link>
```

The only difference is that the first module is in the src/components directory while the failing module is in the src directory.

In App.js (which is also in src directory) the router code includes several modules including both of the ones above:

```
import {
  Switch,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Nav from './Nav';
import Introduction from './components/Introduction.js';
import HowItWorks from './components/HowItWorks.js';
import Blog from './components/Blog.js';
import Shop from './components/Shop.js';
import TheBook from './components/TheBook.js';
import Footer from './Footer.js';


function App() {
    return (
    <> 
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>          
          <Route path="/Introduction" exact component={Introduction}></Route>
          <Route path='/HowItWorks' exact component={HowItWorks}></Route>          
          <Route path="/Shop" exact component={Shop}></Route>
          <Route path="/Blog" exact component={Blog}></Route>
          <Route path="/TheBook" exact component={TheBook}></Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        <Footer />
         
      </div>  
    </>
    );
}

  export default App;
```

If I click the link for "TheBook" in the navbar it works fine... Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: What is in your `<Footer />`?

Comment: Where is the `<Link to="/TheBook">Continue</Link>` being rendered? Error is saying it is outside the `Router`.

Comment: The link is in the module footer.js  This module is exported to App.js  App.js is exported to index.js and App (which includes everything) is rendered there.

Comment: Footer.js contains a link to the module "TheBook", an image and an animated arrow

Comment: function Footer() {
  return (
  <> 
    <div className="FooterFromFooter">     
      <div class="MovingArrow">
        <img class="preorderarrow"src={imgpreorderarrow} alt="alt pre-orderbook"/> 
      </div>

      <div className="BookContainer">
        <img class="imgBlueBook"src={imgBlueBook} alt="The Book"/>

        <div className="ButtonGoToBook">
          <a2 href={"/TheBook"}>Find Out More</a2> 
 {/*         <Link to="/TheBook">Continue</Link> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>

  );  
}

export default Footer;

Comment: This is stranger & stranger...  I moved Footer.js from src to components/src - which had no effect.  I copied all the code from Introduction.JS into Footer.JS because Introduction.js works with a link.  But when the code was copied into Footer.js I get the same invarient issue - with the exact same code!Perhaps it is  something to do with the export to App.js and then to Index.js ???

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was, as I expected, not in the footer.js code but in the App.js code.  The footer.js code needed to be moved inside the Router:

```
function App() {
    return (
    <> 
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
        <Footer />  {/* The footer must be inside the router for the              <link> to work */}
          <Nav />
          <Switch>          
          <Route path="/Introduction" exact component={Introduction}></Route>
          <Route path='/HowItWorks' exact component={HowItWorks}></Route>          
          <Route path="/Shop" exact component={Shop}></Route>
          <Route path="/Blog" exact component={Blog}></Route>
          <Route path="/TheBook" exact component={TheBook}></Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>        
      </div>  
    </>
    );  
}
```

This is now working properly.